# Write csv file as per column name in spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark to write the data to hdfs.
I have two columns id and date. date is of form dd-mm-yyyy.

Is there any way I can create a folder of name which is the date and inside it I can have the csv file.

Example:

```
hdfs path
   -> 11-01-2020
       -> csv file
   -> 01-01-2021
       -> csv file
```

This date would be the column which I am selecting in df.

What I am doing right now is:

```
result = df.selectExpr("id as tid",
            "date")


result.repartition(1)\
          .write\
          .mode ("overwrite")\
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
          .option("header", "true")\
          .save("hdfs path")
```

It creates the part file in this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the output to be partitioned by date:

```
result.repartition("date")\
          .write\
          .partitionBy("date")\
          .mode ("overwrite")\
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
          .option("header", "true")\
          .save("hdfs path")
```

which should give you folder names like `date=01-01-2021`.

Comment: Can i use .repartition(1) in that case as without it, it will create lot of files inside the date folder. And i want only one file

Comment: Yes, I think it should be okay, you can give it a try.

Comment: Or actually `repartition("date")` might be better

Comment: Ok, will give it a try. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: repartition("date") would create one file per partition means for each date.